# Image url still unsafe after I use DomSanitizer

Tags: angular, typescript

I use `DocumentsService` to get an image file from the server after that I use  `URL.createObjectURL(result)` to create image url from server respond, everything seem working fine but I keep get a error about **`sanitizing unsafe URL`** and can't see the image.

```
@Injectable()
export class DocumentsService {

    public url:string = 'api.server.url'

    constructor(private http: HttpClient , private dom: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    public getImageUrl(imageId: string): Observable<any> {

        let requestOptions = {
            params: {
                id: imageId
            },
            responseType: "blob"
        };

        return this._restClientService.get(this.url, requestOptions).map(result => {
            let url = URL.createObjectURL(result);
            return this.dom.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);   
        });
    }
}
```

In my component I have inject the service and

```
this._doc.getImageUrl(doc.id)
          .do(console.log) // => SafeUrlImpl {changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity: "blob:http://localhost:4200/2b9b4820-c7d0-4920-a094-cb3e4cc47c7c"}
          .subscribe(url => this.photoUrl = url)
      }
```

in template I use a function to check if the use have image or not

```
public getImagePath(): string {
    if (this.photoUrl) {
      return this.photoUrl; //  after get the image from documents service
    }
    return FilesUrls.BlankAvatar;
  }
```

template

```
<img src="{{getImagePath()}}" alt="user image">
```

I keep get this error , I think I miss something

> "WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value SafeValue must use
>    [property]=binding:
>    blob:http://localhost:4200/79dd8411-44a8-4e08-96d2-ad6d889c1056 (see
>    http://g.co/ng/security#xss) (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use binding sanitizing is automatic, to set value using attribute you need to call `DomSanitizer.sanitize` with context `SecurityContext.URL`. By the way this is incorrect: `src="{{getImagePath()}}"` should be `[attr.src]="getImagePath()"`

Answer (score 5):

I think you don't return your `SafeUrl` after `bypassSecurityTrustUrl`.

Look at the version which works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqqumm

The code must like :

```
return this._restClientService.get(this.url, requestOptions).map(result => {
     let url = URL.createObjectURL(result);
     return this.dom.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);    
})
```

Comment: sorry that was my mistake when I create the example code from my app. and I can  see the result at console

Comment: .do(console.log) // => SafeUrlImpl {changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity: "blob:http://localhost:4200/2b9b4820-c7d0-4920-a094-cb3e4cc47c7c"}

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi I think that is the problem of version. Because in stackblitz, I did same thing with you but didn't see the warning.

Comment: Can you try bypassSecurityTrustUrl in compoenent, intead of in service pls

Comment: thank you ,the problem was related to template ,i didn't notice that :\

Comment: Stackblitz link is dead. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqqumm

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem is related to my template , I was using `{{getImage Path()}}` , according the error message I have to use property binding rather than interpolated string.

```
<img [src]="getImagePath()" alt="user image">
```

Comment: @ThierryV thanks to **angular team** , the are the real hero here :)

Comment: but getImagePath function will always in  self executing, this is kill application performance !

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me when working with images giving me the same issues.

HTML:

```
<img [src]="currVerifiedLoanOfficerPhoto">
```

Component:

```
this.currVerifiedLoanOfficerPhoto = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + (this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(item) as any).changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity;
```